# Proper use of italics when asking a question.

Tags: discussion, mathjax, markdown, formatting

What are the pros/cons of using two asterisks vs using mathjax when trying to italicize something in a question?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? I think it’s a fair question for a relatively new user.

Comment: downvoting here, just means people usually disagree with the premise.

Comment: Recently I had a post edited and the editor used asterisks instead of mathjax, so I am just trying to understand the reasoning behind that action. Perhaps I could have been more clear what my intent was with this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drawbacks of using MathJaX I can figure are:

- MathJaX can possibly fail with Javascript disabled ( as it's an AJAX ( Asynchronous Javascript And XML)  library emulating LaTeX) which loses the effect.
- Markdown doesn't take a menu to copy a phrase from.
- It might be confused for actual math content, on a math website.
- The word or phrase, won't necessarily be searchable, if the search engine it is searched for on,  doesn't peek inside MathJaX markers.
- Putting a word on a new line takes no less effort
- It's MathJaX, not TextJaX so you have potential to look like a fool.

Pros of using MathJaX:

- Nobody of sane mind, will be willing to edit your words, quote you, or copy your work as is.
- You can add a reference handler to the word, for those that ignore it.
- You can create a post that eats up data, as it requires more processing.
- You can rotate it to make it even more noticable.
- You can add color, make it larger, and add Caligraphical fonts, and move it around the page to be a big fertilized lawn.
- Etc.

Answer (score 11):

Use mathjax for mathematics, not for text formatting. The mathjax italics happen because mathjax thinks "abcde" is just a string of variables.

Comment: Then it should lose `\Large` etc as the normal LaTeX wikibook wouldn't allow it. `\text` is also not the greatest command to have as you can type words between displaystyle math. neither is `\mathit` as it's meant for italicizing in math mode.

Comment: Okay found a use for `\text` and `\Huge` UPC-A barcoding lol